# Profiling GPRBuild

Tags: ada, gprbuild

I have a large GPR based project that can take over 30 minutes to compile.

Having analyzed the build process I noticed many obvious inefficiencies (multiple calls to gprbuild rather than aggregates, excessive use of alternative files rather than configurations, etc). I am wondering if there is some means to 'profile' the build process to see what takes so long.

In particular it takes about 5 minutes to recompile when even a single file changes and there is an error in it. In theory it should be pretty quick to realize that that file has to be recompiled (its the only one that does) and start the compilation process, rapidly discovering the error.

From the verbose output it looks like it takes quite a while just parsing the massive web of gpr files used to define the build, but I would like to know where it spends most of its time.

Thus my question is: Is it possible to profile a build done by gprbuild? If so, how?

Comment: It is my experience that `gprbuild` has a hard time managing lots of source files with individually defined switches.  I never cared enough to check if the problem was specific to defining switches on a per source file basis, or if it was plain project file size that was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From low to high complexity:

- Ask `gprbuild` to report more details about what it is doing with the flag `-vh`.
- Run `gprbuild` through `strace`.
- Rebuild `gprbuild` with the required flags to profile it using `gprof` (but be aware that `gprof` doesn't always tell the truth).

Comment: Answers the question, though disappointingly as a "pretty much no." Is there any hope of perhaps incorporating profiling in future? (e.g. spent 13s parsing gpr files, 15s compiling massive.adb, 1s compiling massive.ads, etc)

Comment: It could probably be done.  An engineer at AdaCore is in the middle of rewriting Gprbuild from scratch, so it isn't a bad time to ask for it.